# WPF: I want to remove the default StrokeDashArray around a custom button

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a custom button which I styled to have an elliptical look. I have added some triggers to give it a click feel and a focused feel.

But the problem is when the button is in focus using the Tab key, I still see the default rectangular StrokeDashArray appear around the button together with my styled focus setting.

[image]

This is the XAML code I have used excluding some lines for brevity.

```
<Button Width="100" Height="100" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontSize="20"
                Margin="0,30,40,35" Content="About" Foreground="#FF5B620F" TabIndex="3">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="Shape">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                ...
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <ContentPresenter  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Shape" Property="Fill" Value="#FFCCFF3A"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Shape" Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FocusVisualStyle describes how your button looks like when its focused: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.focusvisualstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

```
<Button FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
```